# Heston model using YUIMA package

Tags: programming, stochastic-processes, time-series, derivatives, heston

I am trying to estimate a Heston model using the Yuima package, but i am in trouble.

This is my script:

```
# Get financial data and define delta
Delta <- 1/252

getSymbols("DEXUSEU", src = "FRED")
USEU <- setData(na.omit(DEXUSEU), delta=Delta)
```

```
# Define the Heston model
drift <- c("mu*x1", "kappa*(theta-x2)")

diffusion <- matrix(c("c11*sqrt(x2)*x1", "0", "c12*sqrt(x2)*x1",
                      "c22*epsilon*sqrt(x2)"),2,2)

heston <- setModel(drift=drift, diffusion=diffusion, solve.variable = c("x1", "x2"))

# Create the 'yuima' object
mod4 <- setYuima(model=heston, data=USEU)
```

However when I do this, I get the following error:

```
Error in initialize(value, ...) : 
  'initialize' method returned an object of class 'NULL' instead of the required class 'yuima'"
```